# Languages with similar features to JavaFX Script

Tags: javafx

I just completed a small project in JavaFX, only finding that it has been declared dead by Oracle.  JavaFX Script actually seemed to be a pretty interesting language with some neat features for its domain, particularly with bind for data binding and on replace for triggered events.  These features actually make the language very useful for small, quick, RIA type apps, which leads to my question:

**Are there any *mainstream* languages with features similar to bind and on replace?**

After working with JavaFX, I got some ideas for some small personal (academic) projects that could take advantage of these features, but I would prefer to not start anything new in a language considered extinct by its owners.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaFX got [forked](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/fabriziogiudici/archive/2010/09/27/javafx-script-dead-long-live-visage) and [visage](http://code.google.com/p/visage/) was born, you might want to check that out

It's not very mainstream, but again JavaFX was never mainstream as well